# Axios result is undefined after request is repeated from interceptor

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to implement an interceptor which refreshes an expired token and retries the latest request. It works for the most part but when the original request is retried `res`is undefined

This is my original request

```
this.$http.post('/auth/verify')
            .then((res) => {
                this.$store.commit('login', res.data);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(`Error during verify: ${e}`);
            });
```

and this is the interceptor I use

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (err) => {
if (err.response && err.response.status === 401 && err.response.data.message.includes('jwt expired')) {
    const { refreshToken } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
    axios.post('/auth/refresh', { refreshToken })
        .then((res) => {
            axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
            err.config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
            localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify({
                refreshToken,
                token: res.data.token,
            }));

            return axios(err.config);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.error(`Error refreshing token: ${e}`);
        });
    } else {
       return Promise.reject(err);
    }
});
```

Like I said `res` is undefined after the request is retried after the interceptor however in the chrome devtools network tab the second request to `/auth/verify` goes through and returns a correct response which means that the 2nd request to verify was successful.

Comment: if the logic is right then you just have to add `return`  axios.post('/auth/refresh', { refreshToken }). Do let me know if that works.

Comment: Sadly did not work. However I made it work by making the interceptor returning a promise and resolving the `axios(err.config)`

Comment: okay .. yeah that was my next answer. Glad you found it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by making the interceptor return a promise which resolves the `axios(err.config)`